# How to parse file with array of objects gets turned into string

Tags: javascript, json, filereader

I have a text file containing a an array of objects in the following format:

```
[{
            "symbol": "MSFT",
            "side": "BUY",
            "price": 120,
            "quantity": 100
        },
        {
            "symbol": "KPMG",
            "side": "SELL",
            "price": 88,
            "quantity": 10
        }]
```

However, when I upload the file into my application, and store it as a variable, it gets stored as a string. Does anyone know how I can avoid doing this?

I want to be able to read the file in (which I can already do) and store that as an array. So I can go like data[1] and get access to

```
  {
        "symbol": "KPMG",
        "side": "SELL",
        "price": 88,
        "quantity": 10
    }
```

I also want to be able to go like:

```
data[1].side
```

and retrieve the field

Comment: You're looking for a JSON parser.

Comment: Hi Vipin, I read that link but JSON.parse doesn't seem to work on my file

Comment: Why not? What did you do? What happened? Note that `JSON.parse()` does not take a path.

Comment: I made an input button that reads my file in using FileReader. I used reader.readAsText and store the result into a variable.

However, that variable stored my entire array as a string. I'm not able to access any of the objects inside the array because the entire file is treated as a giant string.

Comment: You can use JSON.parse after reading the content

Comment: The variable that stores the string is what you pass: JSON.parse(jsonStringVariable)

Comment: it worked! thank you guys. Sorry for the duplicate question